# Dance dance authentication keeps failing

Tags: discussion, dance-dance-authentication

Dance dance authentication keeps failing. I think everything crunches down to

```
Styleprint.compare(user.styleprint.current);
```

This is called in OnDanceComplete callback where I'm trying to determine success or fail.

What moves am I missing?

https://youtu.be/VgC4b9K-gYU

Comment: This appears to be a programming question and as such belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In some days: *Do we realy have [humor]?*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably attempted to parse a [Twerking](https://youtu.be/H9GsF6prVYA?t=4h19m47s) move.

[image]

The team had to release a hotfix disabling the twerk-recognition subsystem after it was discovered that the algorithm could be fooled  by something as simple as [footage of pick-up trucks performing similar moves](https://youtu.be/H9GsF6prVYA?t=4h19m47s):

[image]

So right now, Twerking is out when building your authentication pattern.

Just use different dance moves. The [Moonwalk](https://youtu.be/b6pomaq30Gg?t=26s) module, for example, is said to be pretty robust.

Whether it was good practice to release the entire thing with bugs this serious, I won't comment on.

Comment: Good to see they're taking proactive measures to curb possible exploit vectors at any rate.

Comment: @BoltClock At first I thought you said "provacative measures" :P

Comment: SO imgur saved the "How to Twerk"-guide above as **"HAQRG.jpg"**. I don't think there could be a more appropriate filename.